# Extract by Attributes resulted in misaligned raster cells

Tags: raster

I want to remove raster cells with a specific value so I am using Extract by Attributes to create a new raster consisting of only the cells containing values I do want. I need the new raster cells to be aligned perfectly with the original but the resulting raster cells are slightly off, even though I used the snap raster function. See photo below. Any ideas?
[image]